# Print keys in yaml, so that they can be used for jsonpath

Tags: kubernetes, jq, jsonpath, yq

```
echo "apiVersion: v1
kind: Node
metadata:
  name: host-cluster-control-plane-64j47
  labels:
    beta.kubernetes.io/arch: amd64
" | yq -o p
```

Result:

```
apiVersion = v1
kind = Node
metadata.name = host-cluster-control-plane-64j47
metadata.labels.beta.kubernetes.io/arch = amd64
```

That's almost what I want. I am looking for the key to get values.

I could use `metadata.name` like this:

```
echo "apiVersion: v1
kind: Node
metadata:
  name: host-cluster-control-plane-64j47
  labels:
    beta.kubernetes.io/arch: amd64
" | yq '.metadata.name'
```

But the `-o p` option of `yq` does not quote the key, if needed.

I can't use `metadata.labels.beta.kubernetes.io/arch` as key, since the correct syntax is `metadata.labels["beta.kubernetes.io/arch"]`.

Is there an automated way to get the keys of a yaml file so that I can use the keys in `yq` (or `jq`)?

The desired output would be something like this:

```
apiVersion = v1
kind = Node
metadata.name = host-cluster-control-plane-64j47
metadata.labels["beta.kubernetes.io/arch"] = amd64
```

I am looking for the valid key, because I want to create a second command line to select these values.

For example:

```
❯ k get nodes -o yaml | yq '.items[].metadata.labels["beta.kubernetes.io/arch"]'

amd64
amd64
amd64
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "the correct syntax"? What (exact) criteria disambiguates the ways how level `metadata` and level `labels` are glued together (here `A.B`) from how level `labels` and level `beta.kubernetes.io/arch` are (here `A["B"]`). Is it only the presence of dots (and/or maybe the slash) in "B"? What if these are present in "A" (on top-level)? Please define or include more samples.

Comment: @pmf I added this to the question: I am looking for the valid key, because I want to create a second commadn line to select these values. For example ...

Is it more clear now?

Comment: Yes, apparently you want to generate code parseable by yq (although I still can't follow why you want the dot omitted on top-level). However, this looks like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). If your ultimate goal is to retrieve (or otherwise process) values at given paths, rather focus on extracting pure data (the paths in this case) in a post-processable way (e.g. `yq '.. | select(tag == "!!str") | path | . style="flow"'` or `yq '.. | select(tag == "!!str") | [{"path": path, "value": .}]'`), and then operate on/with that instead. Embedding generated code is rarely a good idea.

Comment: Agree with @pmf if what you are going to process the path with `yq` output the path array and then you can later use the setpath path operation...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get close by doing something like:

```bash
yq '(.. | key | select(test("\."))) |= ("[\"" + . + "\"]")' file.yaml -op

apiVersion = v1
kind = Node
metadata.name = host-cluster-control-plane-64j47
metadata.labels.["beta.kubernetes.io/arch"] = amd64
```

Or you could do:

```
yq '(.. | key | select(test("\."))) |= sub("\.", "\.")' file.yaml -op

apiVersion = v1
kind = Node
metadata.name = host-cluster-control-plane-64j47
metadata.labels.beta\\.kubernetes\\.io/arch = amd64
```

BTW - I'm not sure how it's supposed be escaped in property files, I'd be willing to update yq to do it natively someone raises a bug with details on github...

Disclaimer: I wrote yq

Answer (score 3):

Be forewarned that you're trying to abuse the half-baked yq -o=props output but it will not do what you want even if it was correctly implemented<sup>1</sup> because JSONPath uses `\.` to escape those dots, even though that may be a kubectl-ism since that syntax [isn't documented](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-goessner-dispatch-jsonpath-00.html#name-overview-of-jsonpath-expres):

```
$ kubectl get no -o jsonpath='{.items[*].metadata.labels.beta\.kubernetes\.io/arch}'
amd64
```

It may be possible to do special handling for `annotations:`, `labels:`, `selector:`, and other free-form key-value pairs in the kubernetes objects that interest you, but for sure it's not going to work in the general case the way you wanted it to

*apologies for the `jq` in this, I don't know how to do this in `yq`* and of course you can use any placeholder character you'd like, I just know tab characters cannot appear in kubernetes annotations nor labels

```
$ echo '
apiVersion: v1
kind: Node
metadata:
  labels:
    beta.kubernetes.io/arch: amd64
' | yq -o=json | jq '
.metadata.labels = (
  [.metadata.labels|to_entries[]
  | {key: .key|gsub("[.]";"\t"), value}
  ]
  |from_entries)' | yq -o=p | sed -Ee 's@\\t@\\.@g'
apiVersion = v1
kind = Node
metadata.labels.beta\.kubernetes\.io/arch = amd64
```

*fn 1:* someone else [raised that same concern](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/issues/140) and it went just as poorly, and I said "incorrectly implemented" because `echo '{"alpha.beta":{"charlie":1}}' | yq -o=p | yq -p=p` does not round trip

It seems [the properties library](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/blob/v4.32.2/go.mod#L13) does not [allow escaping `.`](https://github.com/magiconair/properties/blob/v1.8.7/lex.go#L338-L352). I even tried being sneaky with `beta\u002Ekubernetes` but it seems the unicode escape processing happens before the key lexing does and thus suffers from the same bug

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. It seems there is no perfect solution to my question. `yq -o p` works for my case. I can do the necessary quoting by hand. I was just curious if there is a tool which can help me to address the needed keys.

Answer (score 0):

### PYTHON

Aware that the ask is `yq`, however as an out of the box thinking option, the keys can be printed using a python script. Based on `Python 3`, using Python modules `argparse` and `pyyaml`, installed using `pip3`

To execute script:
`python3 yaml_to_json.py <file>`

**Script: yaml_to_json.py**

```py
import argparse
import yaml

def print_keys(data, prefix=""):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for key, value in data.items():
            new_prefix = f"{prefix}.{key}" if prefix else key
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                print_keys(value, new_prefix)
            elif isinstance(value, list):
                for i, item in enumerate(value):
                    print_keys(item, f"{new_prefix}[{i}]")
            else:
                if "." in key:
                    print(f'{new_prefix}["{key}"] = {value}')
                else:
                    print(f'{new_prefix} = {value}')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Print keys in a YAML file for JSONPath")
    parser.add_argument("yaml_file", type=str, help="path to YAML file")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    with open(args.yaml_file, "r") as f:
        data = yaml.safe_load(f)
        for key, value in data.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                for k, v in value.items():
                    if isinstance(v, dict):
                        for sub_k, sub_v in v.items():
                            new_key = f"{k}[\"{sub_k}\"]"
                            print(f"metadata.{new_key} = {sub_v}")
                    else:
                        new_key = f"metadata.{k}"
                        print(f"{new_key} = {v}")
            else:
                print(f"{key} = {value}")
```

The result is:

```
apiVersion = v1
kind = Node
metadata.name = host-cluster-control-plane-64j47
metadata.labels["beta.kubernetes.io/arch"] = amd64
```

Explanation:

- The 1st block defines a function to print the keys that will recursively traverse the data and print the keys/values in the format for use with JSONPath.
- The 2nd block defines argparse parser to parse the command line argument to the file.
- The 3rd block opens the file, loads the data using yaml.safe_load(), traverses the data to print the keys. The metadata prefix is added to the keys to match the desired output format.